# Unable to perform a covered (indexOnly) query with mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a query built around a composite index, and I've verified from the mongo shell that this query can run as an index only query.

Output:

```
db.merchants.find({st:{"$regex" : "cr", "$options": "i"}}, {n:1, _id:1})
{ "n" : "Crab shack", "_id" : ObjectId("51c908cc1925f3ca51000001") }
{ "n" : "Tacos R Us", "_id" : ObjectId("51c16f201925f3df4300001b") }
db.merchants.find({st:{"$regex" : "cr", "$options": "i"}}, {n:1, _id:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor st_1_n_1__id_1 multi",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : true,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "st" : [
            [
                "",
                {

                }
            ],
            [
                /cr/i,
                /cr/i
            ]
        ],
        "n" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "MacBook-Pro.local:27017"
}
```

But the same query run from the rails console using mongoid gives me:

```
Merchant.where({:st => { '$regex'=> "cr", '$options' => 'i' } }).only(:_id, :n).explain
=> {
    "cursor"=>"BtreeCursor st_1_n_1__id_1 multi",
    "isMultiKey"=>false, 
    "n"=>2, 
    "nscannedObjects"=>2, 
    "nscanned"=>2, 
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans"=>2, 
    "nscannedAllPlans"=>2, 
    "scanAndOrder"=>false, 
    "indexOnly"=>false, 
    "nYields"=>0, 
    "nChunkSkips"=>0, 
    "millis"=>0, 
    "indexBounds"=>{
        "st"=>[["", {}], [/cr/i, /cr/i]], 
        "n"=>[[{"$minElement"=>1}, {"$maxElement"=>1}]], "_id"=>[[{"$minElement"=>1}, {"$maxElement"=>1}]]
    }, 
    "allPlans"=>[{"cursor"=>"BtreeCursor st_1_n_1__id_1 multi", "n"=>2, "nscannedObjects"=>2, "nscanned"=>2, "index
Bounds"=>{"st"=>[["", {}], [/cr/i, /cr/i]], "n"=>[[{"$minElement"=>1}, {"$maxElement"=>1}]], "_id"=>[[{"$minElement"=>1}, {"$maxElement"=>1}]]}}], "oldPlan"=>{"cursor"=>"Btr
eeCursor st_1_n_1__id_1 multi", "indexBounds"=>{"st"=>[["", {}], [/cr/i, /cr/i]], "n"=>[[{"$minElement"=>1}, {"$maxElement"=>1}]], "_id"=>[[{"$minElement"=>1}, {"$maxElement
"=>1}]]}}, "server"=>"Arvinds-MacBook-Pro.local:27017"}
```

I suspect this is because of the only() modifier. Or is this a bug?

EDIT:
I'm using Mongoid v3.1.4 and mongod v2.2

Here is the query that mongod is seeing from mongoid:
Mon Jul 15 10:47:26 [conn14] runQuery called spl_development.merchants { $query: { st: { $regex: "cr", $options: "i" } }, $explain: true }
Mon Jul 15 10:47:26 [conn14] query spl_development.merchants query: { $query: { st: { $regex: "cr", $options: "i" } }, $explain: true } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:212 nreturned:1 reslen:393 0ms

So the projection isn't being sent to the mongod layer and only just handles it in the application layer. Not ideal!

Comment: have you tried to enable mongod log and see the query that mongoid is sending to server?

Comment: what version of mongod are you using?  looks like you are getting incorrect nscannedObjects which suggests an older than current version.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether **only** actually sets the projection when it sends the query to MongoDB. If you check the log (after setting logging high enough to show all queries) you should see which query was actually sent, including the "projection". This will show you whether Mongoid actually sends it, or just interprets "only" in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the query sent to MongoDB in the logs with the same query without calling `explain`. On MongoDB 2.2 / Mongoid 3.1.4 I see the correct query sent to the DB. Look for the `fields=` directive in the Moped logs.